# WP_Query random ordering not working since 5.4

Tags: wp-query, order

My random sorting of custom posts isn't working since I upgraded to WordPress 5.4. This is the query that I am using:

```
      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'client',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '7', // you may edit this number
        'paged'                 => $paged,
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'meta_query'        => array ( array ('key' => 'wpcf-featured-post', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '='))
      );

      $client_items = null;
      $client_items = new WP_Query($args);
```

Has something changed in 5.4 to sort posts randomly?

Thank you.

Comment: Nohting has changed to sort posts. Have you made any other change in your site? Could check the actual query that is performed? Something like `var_dump( $client_items )` could help to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the problem, the plugin Post Types Order was adding an orderby menu id to all queries. Unchecking an option in it's settings has fixed the issue.